# EPPLUS issue with plotting combination chart with Vb.net code

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, epplus

[i added image for clarity, you can see that instead of plotting 2 separate columns i am getting stacked column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux1sX.png) here is the function which takes datatable as input.and i am plotting column and line series alternatively

```
    Private Sub CreateCharts(ByVal chartDt As DataTable,
                         ByVal workbook As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook)
    Dim worksheet As ExcelWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test")
    Dim windowInfo As ExcelWorksheetView = worksheet.View
    Dim chart As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChart
    Dim excelSeries As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChartSerie
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    windowInfo.ShowGridLines = False
    chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart name", 
    Drawing.Chart.eChartType.Line)

    Dim row1 As Integer = 4 + (count * chartDt.Rows.Count) + count
    Dim col1 As Integer = 47
    Dim row2 As Integer = (row1 + chartDt.Rows.Count)
    Dim col2 As Integer = (col1 + chartDt.Columns.Count - 1)
    Dim sourceData As ExcelRange = worksheet.Cells(row1, col1, row2, 
    col2)

    Dim rowStart As Integer = row1
    Dim rowEnd As Integer = row2
    Dim colStart As Integer = col1
    Dim colEnd As Integer = col1
```

load data from datatable.

```
      sourceData.LoadFromDataTable(chartDt, True)
      ConvertCellValuesToDouble(worksheet.Cells(row1, col1, row2, col2), 
      row1, col1, row2, col2)
      chart.Legend.Position = Drawing.Chart.eLegendPosition.Bottom
```

then iterate through each column, create column and line series.
For adding series i used address instead of cell/column name hard coding

```
    For col As Integer = 1 To chartDt.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim colName As String = chartDt.Columns(col).ColumnName
        Dim seriesAddress = ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(rowStart + 1, 
        colStart + col, rowEnd, colStart + col)
        Dim xAxisAddress = ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(rowStart + 1, 
        colStart, rowEnd, colStart)

        worksheet.Cells(seriesAddress).Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.0"
        worksheet.Cells(seriesAddress).Style.Font.Italic = True

        Dim _Chart As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChart
        If col Mod 2 = 0 Then
            _Chart = 
         chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(Drawing.Chart.eChartType.Line)
            _Chart.UseSecondaryAxis = True
            excelSeries = _Chart.Series.Add(seriesAddress, xAxisAddress)
        Else
            _Chart = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(Drawing.Chart.eChartType.ColumnStacked)
            _Chart.UseSecondaryAxis = False
            excelSeries = _Chart.Series.Add(seriesAddress, xAxisAddress)
        End If
        excelSeries.Header = colName
    Next

    chart.XAxis.Title.Text = "RecordDate"

    chart.YAxis.MinorGridlines.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Silver

    chart.YAxis.Title.Text = "Values"
    chart.XAxis.MajorUnit = 2

    chart.Title.Text = "ChartDemo1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code worked for me.
There are 2 changes here, first i am declaring chart as ColumnClustered instead of line,
then i am adding different line series it makes chart a combination chart. (other way didn't work like first declare as chart then adding ColumnClustered)
second change is line number 29 and 30

```
    Dim chartTypeCol As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChart = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes(0)
    Dim chartTypeLine As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChart = 
    chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(Drawing.Chart.eChartType.Line)
```

here is the entire working function, I think this is the workaround for my issue

```
    Private Sub CreateCharts(ByVal chartDt As DataTable,
                         ByVal workbook As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook)
    Dim worksheet As ExcelWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test")
    Dim windowInfo As ExcelWorksheetView = worksheet.View
    Dim chart As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChart
    Dim excelSeries As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChartSerie
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    windowInfo.ShowGridLines = False
    chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart name", Drawing.Chart.eChartType.ColumnClustered)

    Dim row1 As Integer = 4 + (count * chartDt.Rows.Count) + count
    Dim col1 As Integer = 47
    Dim row2 As Integer = (row1 + chartDt.Rows.Count)
    Dim col2 As Integer = (col1 + chartDt.Columns.Count - 1)
    Dim sourceData As ExcelRange = worksheet.Cells(row1, col1, row2, col2)

    Dim rowStart As Integer = row1
    Dim rowEnd As Integer = row2
    Dim colStart As Integer = col1
    Dim colEnd As Integer = col1

    sourceData.LoadFromDataTable(chartDt, True)
    ConvertCellValuesToDouble(worksheet.Cells(row1, col1, row2, col2), row1, col1, row2, col2)
    chart.Legend.Position = Drawing.Chart.eLegendPosition.Bottom
    chart.SetSize(750, 300)

    Dim chartTypeCol As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChart = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes(0)
    Dim chartTypeLine As Drawing.Chart.ExcelChart = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(Drawing.Chart.eChartType.Line)


    For col As Integer = 1 To chartDt.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim colName As String = chartDt.Columns(col).ColumnName
        Dim seriesAddress = ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(rowStart + 1, colStart + col, rowEnd, colStart + col)
        Dim xAxisAddress = ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(rowStart + 1, colStart, rowEnd, colStart)

        worksheet.Cells(seriesAddress).Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.0"
        worksheet.Cells(seriesAddress).Style.Font.Italic = True

        If col Mod 2 = 0 Then
            excelSeries = chartTypeCol.Series.Add(seriesAddress, xAxisAddress)
        Else
            excelSeries = chartTypeLine.Series.Add(seriesAddress, xAxisAddress)
        End If
        excelSeries.Header = colName
    Next

    chart.XAxis.Title.Text = "RecordDate"

    chart.YAxis.MinorGridlines.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Silver

    chart.YAxis.Title.Text = "Values"
    chart.XAxis.MajorUnit = 2

    chart.Title.Text = "ChartDemo1"
    chart.XAxis.Title.Font.Size = 8
    chart.YAxis.Title.Font.Size = 8
    chart.YAxis.Title.Font.Size = 8
    chart.Title.Font.Size = 8
End Sub
```